# solrnet with StructureMap

Tags: structuremap, solrnet

I have a question about solrnet, and more specifically about mapping fields to C# objects.

I have the following code:

```
var mgr = new MappingManager();
mgr.Add(typeof(Article).GetProperty("Title"), "newsTitle");

SolrServerElement news = new SolrServerElement();
news.Id = "news";
news.DocumentType = typeof(Article).AssemblyQualifiedName;
news.Url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/solrNews/news";

SolrServers servers = new SolrServers();
servers.Add(news);

ObjectFactory.Initialize(
    x =>
    {
        x.AddRegistry(
        new SolrNetRegistry(servers)
        );

        x.For<IReadOnlyMappingManager>().Use(mgr);
    }
);

_solr = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Article>>();
_solr.Ping();
```

It does not appear to map the solr fields to the object properties in C#. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the MappingManager working correctly you need to eject IReadOnlyMappingManager from ObjectFactory first of all, and *then* configure it to use your own MappingManager.

So it would be something like this:

```
var mgr = new MappingManager();
mgr.Add(typeof(Article).GetProperty("Title"), "newsTitle");

ObjectFactory.EjectAllInstancesOf<IReadOnlyMappingManager>();
ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.For<IReadOnlyMappingManager>().Use(mgr));
```

Comment: Cool, glad it worked out. I still wonder though why the overriding registration didn't work in your case...

Comment: yes, it is very odd! Although it is similar in logic to how you would do it using the built-in container http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/OverridingMappingMechanism

Answer (score 2):

IIRC StructureMap has a convention of "last registration wins", i.e. it becomes the default for the service. So if you register your IReadOnlyMappingManager after adding the SolrNetRegistry it should become the default.

Comment: I have updated the question with your suggestions but it still does not seem to work. Can you advise?

Comment: @MichaelS : seems to have worked for this guy: http://groups.google.com/group/solrnet/browse_thread/thread/13db63c0054a85d6